# Adding dependencies to a Nuxt 3 app gives me a strange error, it did not do this before

Tags: dependencies, nuxt.js, dependency-management, nuxtjs3

I can create a nuxt app using `npx nuxi init \<app-name\>`, but when I try to install dependencies I get the following error:

```
apps/base-app prepare$ nuxt prepare Nuxi 3.3.1
ERROR Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at normalizedModule
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "@colossal/base-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "PORT=3000 nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "prepare": "nuxt prepare",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

I've tried different versions of `nuxt 3`, but I literally was able to spin up so many apps just yesterday and now I'm seeing this error anytime I try and add dependencies to any new `Nuxt` project. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

## Check your node version

Apparently this is an issue with my node version, I am on 14 but there is a github issues ticket open about this very thing: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19682

I'm going to try upgrading my node and will update if that worked at all.

Edit: It did work, there's an issue with node v14, 16, and 19 specifically even though sometimes in the error they say it is not an issue with node. I ran the following commands to change my node version:

### Using nvm:

**Check current node version:**

```
node -v
```

**Use latest ('long term support' version)**

```
  nvm install --lts

  nvm use --lts
```

### On Macos, optionally using Brew:

To see what versions I had installed

```
brew search node
```

To unlink my current version -

```
brew unlink node@14
```

To upgrade brew (it's been a while) -

```
brew upgrade
```

To install a working version -

```
brew install node@18
```

Add brew to path -

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@18/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Link the new node version -

```
brew link node@18
```

Check node version (in my case it still showed node@14) -

```
node -v
```

I had to uninstall node@14 before it used node@18, this may not be the case for you -

```
brew uninstall node@14
```

I checked my version again and it was 18. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is my experience as well. Was using node 14.21.1, and switched to 18.12.1 and the error disappeared.